# Storing data from firebase child key value pairs as an array

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I store key value pairs from firebase into an array? I've tried writing a code to send some data to firebase from a local array and noticed they are stored in such form:

[image]

notice how the 'medals' child are stored.

I'm trying to take a snapshot of the array from the 'medals' object and return it as an array in swift.

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        databaseRef.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user medals
            self.identities3 = snapshot.value!["medals"] as! [String]

        })
```

I know this is very crude, but would it work?

Thanks! Still pretty new to firebase and learning :)

Comment: This should work, have you tested it to see if it does?

Comment: Yup, I set it to print at the log and it showed an empty array []

Comment: In that case, your best bet is using the below code provided by Dravidian. It immediately solves your problem, and is also a much safer way of structuring your data.

Comment: Thanks, still working on it. But there are still some errors. And using this method might not make it easy to save data to the database in the future.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    databaseRef.child("users").child(userID!).child("medals").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user medals
        self.identities3 = snapshot.value as! [String]

    })
```

Comment: Yup that worked! Actually, I wanted to test that out too but you got to me first :P thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing your JSON structure to :-

```
Medals: {
       Shield : true,
       Tie : true 
      }
```

To retrieve:-

**Swift 3**

```
  let array = [String]()
   FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("medals").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in


        if let snapDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{


            for each in snapDict{

                print(each.key)
                self.array.append(each.key)
            }
        }
    })
```

**Swift 2**

```
  let array = [String]()
   FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("medals").observeSingleOfEvent(.Value, withBlock: {(snap) in


        if let snapDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{


            for each in snapDict{

                print(each.0)
                self.array.append(each.0)
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: It says value of tuple type (String, AnyObject) has no member 'key'

Comment: I have updated my answer. Swift syntax just changed...Still adjusting..:)

Comment: Ok, this pretty hardcore.There are like a dozen difference ways of doing this. Everyone is telling me something different. YOU should be writing the docs for Google.  :-)

Can I refer you to my question?  Don't think I need swiftyJSON, but shows the structure. Other solutions (swift3) most welcome. Thanks!  :-)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851347/firebase-and-swiftyjson-parsing-quetion